# Bios start screen is shown even though UEFI fast boot is enabled

Tags: windows, boot, bios, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 from scratch (clean install) to avoid problems which could arise when upgrading my old Windows 8.1 to 10. Everything went well and new installation booted up very fast.

Problems started when I put my computer to sleep overnight and then wake it up next afternoon. I got only black screen and nothing appears any of my attached 3 monitors. I tried to shut the computer down by pressing power button, but it didn't work because there is probably some prompt on screen that there is logged on accounts which may lose information if I shut the computer down. So I just pressed power button for 10 seconds to force it to shut off. When I started the computer the BIOS start screen appeared (it does every time after restart or dirty shutdown). But problem is that it appears even after clean shut down.

I checked event viewer for errors and there is notification that fast boot was not successful. During Windows start there is that default blue Windows logo instead of my motherboard logo. I reset BIOS to its default settings and then that error disappeared in event viewer and during Windows startup there is ROG logo, so fast boot is now working. But I still have to wait several seconds for BIOS screen to disappear. Its silly to wait some 10 seconds in BIOS screen and then only 1-2 second (no lie it's real fast) that the Windows start. How to re-enable UEFI GOP to get rid of BIOS screen? It was okay just after install so is reinstalling Windows the only way to fix this?

My computer specs:

MOBO: Asus ROG Maximus Hero VI

CPU: i7 4770K

GPU: nVidia GTX 970

SSD: Samsung 840 Pro

Comment: Random down votes fixed... Please comment on down votes.

Comment: Have you tried jumping the BIOS? Maybe could be the same thing as resetting the BIOS via its software, but it's worth a shot.